# WebProfiler is not loaded on custom environment

Tags: symfony

I'm running into a very weird issue. I have created 4 environments:

1. frontend_dev
2. frontend_prod
3. backend_dev
4. backend_prod

In frontend_dev, the profiler is shown at the bottom of the page as it should be. However, on the backend_dev environment it is not shown. Upon investigation I have found out that the piece of code to load the profiler is actually there at the body end tag, however the call to get the profiler content doesn't return anything at all.

Further investigation showed that the loadProfile method failed because $this->storage->read($token) returns NULL.

I wonder what is happening, seems like somehow the storage couldn't save the profile and thus could not read it upon request?

---

Edit 1:

I think I know why: previously both my frontend and my backend were using the same environment (dev) and the profiler cached the toolbar content to the same place. However, now that we are using 2 environments the profiler caches the toolbar content to backend_dev but attempts to load from frontend_dev cache folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason as described above, in the end for the sake of simplicity (and also other reasons) I have separated my original app into 2 apps using [this guide](http://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2)

So far it has worked out very well for me.